# mod_rewrite rewrites to directory twice?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My index page and links like /page work fine, however my rewrite rule to remove the php from the /page.php seems to be writing the url incorrectly.

Example: http://www.example.com/folder/page.php will redirect to http://www.example.com/folder/folder/page which does not exist

```
# Remove .php extention
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301]

# Rewrite to PHP file extension (if existing) without changing url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What should `http://www.example.com/folder/page.php` be redirected to?

Comment: http://www.example.com/folder/page

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you put the above code in `.htaccess` file in this directory `http://www.example.com/folder/` so when a page comes without .php it will be handled fine for example if you request `http://www.example.com/folder/page` it will give you this result `http://www.example.com/folder/page` , without .php because it will be handled by the second section of your given code

`# Rewrite to PHP file extension (if existing) without changing url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]`

it means when file comes without .php will result the same file , good.

but the problem when you write the same request along with `.php` so the request will be `http://www.example.com/folder/page.php` and this according to section one of your code

`# Remove .php extention
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301]`

will immediately remove the extension `.php` correctly but the problem is in  line of code:

```
 RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301]
```

The path in a RewriteRule target is incorrect so you see it twice and you should add

`RewriteBase /`

line above

`RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301]`

or just replace it with :

`RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301]`

and it will work fine .    `

Comment: This helped a little, and the redirect for example.com/folder/page works fine but then my second section wasn't rewriting properly. I was getting nothing but 404 pages, but changing the last line seems to have fixed it.

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ folder/$1.php [L]

Any ideas why this worked since the rewrite base should already be set to / ?

Comment: where do you put .htaccess file ? in which directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
# remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite to PHP file extension (if existing) without changing url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: It isnt an issue with the condition, seems to be something with the rewrite base.

Comment: There is no `RewriteBase` in my answer. What URL is causing problem for you? Can you update the question with latest .htaccess

Comment: The original question is a part of my very long htaccess file, and I do have a RewriteBase / in my htaccess file. In the comment to the other answer I do explain a change that works for me.

Comment: You don't need to use `folder/$1.php` if `php` file and `.htaccess` are in same directory